# How do I create a WebBrowser element with code, instead of dragging it in?

Tags: c#, browser

Currently I can drag a WebBrowser element in the design area and a webbrowser is made. How do I make a webbrowser with code?

Answer (score 1):

Drag & Drop a web browser control into your form (Form1), and checking the source code in Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: There's the properties but not the actual creation.

Comment: WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();    this.controls.add(browser);

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in Winforms?

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
```

This is the same for any Winforms control.

If you want to set properties for the control you can do this when declaring:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser() { Width = 500, Height = 500 };
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
```

Or before adding to the the control collection:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.Width = 500;
webBrowser.Height = 500;
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
```

Or after adding:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
this.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
this.Controls["webBrowser"].Width = 500;
this.Controls["webBrowser"].Height = 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, just name the Grid/Stack. Like for my case, i would name my Grid as 'grid'. Then to add it into the form, i would do this.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
grid.Children.Add(wb);
```

Subsequently, if you need to shift it left or right, you would need to mess with the margin.

```
Thickness t = new Thickness { Top = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5, Bottom = 5 };
wb.Margin = t;
```

Hope this helps.